# Set boundaries equal to overlayImage google maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

i'm trying to set the boundaries so that you cant pan away from the overlayImages boundaries. however even though i've found lots of threads here i cant seem to make it work what am i doing wrong?

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  center: {lat: 40.740, lng: -74.18},
  zoom : 15,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var imageBounds = {
  north: 40.773941,
  south: 40.712216,
  east: -74.12544,
  west: -74.22655
};
historicalOverlay = new google.maps.GroundOverlay(
'https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mgx2.jpg',
imageBounds);
historicalOverlay.setMap(map);


var strictBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
  new google.maps.LatLng(40.773941, -74.12544), 
  new google.maps.LatLng(40.712216, -74.22655)
);

// Listen for the dragend event
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function() {
  if (strictBounds.contains(map.getCenter())) return;

  // We're out of bounds - Move the map back within the bounds

  var c = map.getCenter(),
      x = c.lng(),
      y = c.lat(),
      maxX = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lng(),
      maxY = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lat(),
      minX = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lng(),
      minY = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lat();

  if (x < minX) x = minX;
  if (x > maxX) x = maxX;
  if (y < minY) y = minY;
  if (y > maxY) y = maxY;

  map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(y, x));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed up parameters for `google.maps.LatLngBounds`. First is South-West corner and second is North-East corner. Try this instead of your `strictBounds`:

```
var strictBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(   
  new google.maps.LatLng(imageBounds.south, imageBounds.west),
  new google.maps.LatLng(imageBounds.north, imageBounds.east)
);
```

If you also want to disallow zooming out of the area too much, or zooming in too much, you can use `minZoom` and `maxZoom` parameters when creating a map, like this:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  center: {lat: 40.740, lng: -74.18},
  zoom : 15,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  minZoom: 12, 
  maxZoom: 14
});
```

Also I recommend using `bounds_changed` instead of `dragend`, in my opinion it provides much smoother experience for the user. So you would have:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() { ...
```

One last thing. The algorithm you are using only makes sure that the CENTER of the map won't pan out of the `strictBounds`. So user will be able to see part of the underlying map when panning around sides of the image. Using this algorithm you won't get better results (I currently don't know of a better solution though).